# Using class weight to balance data set lowers accuracy in RBF SVM

Tags: python-2.7, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification, svm

I have been using sklearn to learn on some data. This is a binary classifcation task and I am using a RBF kernel. My data set is quite unbalanced (80:20) and I'm using only 120 samples, with 10ish features (I've been experimenting with a few less). Since I set `class_weight="auto"` the accuracy I've calculated from a cross validated (10 folds) gridsearch has dropped dramatically. Why??

I will include a couple of validation accuracy heatmaps to demonstrate the difference.
[image: This is before I changed class weight to auto]

[image: This is with class weight set to auto]

NOTE: top heatmap is before classweight was changed to auto.

Answer (score 0):

Accuracy is not the best metrics to use when dealing with unbalanced dataset. Let's say you have 99 positive examples and 1 negative example, and if you predict all outputs to be positive, still you will get 99% accuracy, whereas you have mis-classified the only negative example. You might have gotten high accuracy in the first case because your predictions will be on the side which has high number of samples.

When you do class weight = auto, it takes the imbalance into consideration and hence, your predictions might have moved towards center, you can cross-check it using plotting the histograms of predictions.

My suggestion is, don't use accuracy as performance metric, use something like [F1 Score](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F1_score) or [AUC](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.auc.html).

Comment: I've been checking the true positive rate, as well as analysing the exact performance and prior to changing the class weight the predictor(at best) got 5 or 6 of the 24 in the minority group. After changing it however its yet to get more than one